# Is this a reference escape to a partially constructed object?

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, future

I want to run a CompletableFuture property on a given class. If i have initialized like so, would that be dangerous and possibly create a partially constructed object?

```
public class MyClass { 

    public final CompletableFuture<BigDecimal> myExpensiveVal = CompletableFuture.supplyASync(() -> calculateExpensiveMethod(this));

//...
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would be a field initializer.

Comment: I made some edits to make it technically correct. I should have composed this in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CompletableFuture.supplyASync` sends the provided `Supplier` to another thread and, *of course*, if this supplier has any reference to your instance under construction, it is a leakage of `this` which makes an incomplete object instance visible to other threads and even voids any `final` publication guaranty.

In this special case it’s so obvious that you can spot this escaping reproducibly:

```
public class EscapingThis {

    public final CompletableFuture<BigDecimal> myExpensiveVal
                = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> calculateExpensiveMethod(this));
    final int fourtyTwo;

    public EscapingThis() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+" starts creating "+this);
        try {
            myExpensiveVal.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException|ExecutionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger("EscapingThis").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("still incomplete");
        fourtyTwo=42;
        System.out.println("leaving constructor");
    }

    static BigDecimal calculateExpensiveMethod(EscapingThis instance) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()
                                 +" says: hello incomplete instance "+instance);
        System.out.println("fourtyTwo = "+instance.fourtyTwo);
        return BigDecimal.ONE;
    }
    public static void main(String... arg) {
        new EscapingThis();
    }
}
```

Here you will see `hello incomplete instance EscapingThis@1a9515` and `fourtyTwo = 0` before `still incomplete` and `leaving constructor` *for sure*. But you might even see the `Thread[main,5,main] starts creating …` message after the `hello incomplete …` message as the timing is undefined.

Note that if `calculateExpensiveMethod` is an instance method, it doesn’t need the `this` parameter to let the instance leak. The implied reference to `this` on which the instance method will be invoked is also a leaking reference.